# MySQL - count occurence in multiple columns?

Tags: mysql

I want to count occurrences of each person according to their posts, regardless of the date.

The data is like this:

```
date       | post1    | post2    | post3
--------------------------------------------
01/01/2016 | Anna     | Bella    | Charlie
03/01/2016 | Bella    | Charlie  | Dan
05/01/2016 | Dan      | Charlie  | Evan
06/01/2016 | Charlie  | Anna     | Evan
```

The expected result is:

```
name     | post1    | post2    | post3
-------------------------------------------
Anna     | 1        | 1        | 0
Bella    | 1        | 1        | 0
Charlie  | 1        | 2        | 1
Dan      | 1        | 0        | 1
Evan     | 0        | 0        | 2
```

Currently, I can output the count result for each post using GROUP BY, like this:

```
SELECT post1 as name, COUNT(post1) as count FROM data GROUP BY name
(data from post1)
name     | count
-------------------
Anna     | 1       
Bella    | 1       
Charlie  | 1       
Dan      | 1       

SELECT post2 as name, COUNT(post1) as count FROM data GROUP BY name
(data from post2)
name     | count
-------------------
Anna     | 1       
Bella    | 1       
Charlie  | 2
```

But I want to output it like the expected result, where it counts all posts simultaneously. Is that possible using just query or do I need to make a stored procedure?

Comment: that'd be a pivot query, which mysql doesn't support. the workarounds get very ugly, very fast, and cannot handle arbitrary numbers of row/column->column/row transforms. do this in client-side code.

Comment: ...or, more obviously, normalise your schema

Answer (score 0):

The correct approach would be along these lines:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(date DATE NOT NULL
,user VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
,post_no INT NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(date,post_no)
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
('2016-01-01','Anna',1),
('2016-01-03','Bella',1),
('2016-01-05','Dan',1),
('2016-01-06','Charlie',1),
('2016-01-01','Bella',2),
('2016-01-03','Charlie',2),
('2016-01-05','Charlie',2),
('2016-01-06','Anna',2),
('2016-01-01','Charlie',3),
('2016-01-03','Dan',3),
('2016-01-05','Evan',3),
('2016-01-06','Evan',3);

SELECT user,post_no,COUNT(*) total FROM my_table GROUP BY user,post_no;
+---------+---------+----------+
| user    | post_no | total    |
+---------+---------+----------+
| Anna    |       1 |        1 |
| Anna    |       2 |        1 |
| Bella   |       1 |        1 |
| Bella   |       2 |        1 |
| Charlie |       1 |        1 |
| Charlie |       2 |        2 |
| Charlie |       3 |        1 |
| Dan     |       1 |        1 |
| Dan     |       3 |        1 |
| Evan    |       3 |        2 |
+---------+---------+----------+
```

Any remaining aspects of this problem are best resolved in application level code.

Comment: Actually if he'd normalize his data, conditional aggregation could easily be done here.

Comment: Yes, but why would you bother - unless you really had no access to a presentation layer?